# Input is not working, but works elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html, input

My Input works in 2 other places, but when I use the same ID on the mobile version it doesn't work and I am not sure why.

HTML:

```
<div id="searchContainer">
    <input id="searchIconMain">
    <img src="{% static 'publicnfx/images/search.png' %}" alt="" id="searchIcon">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#searchBarMain").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        search(e);
    }
});
$("#searchIconMain").on('click', function (e) {
    search(e);
});
```

searchBarMain is used as the desktop version currently.

CSS:

```
div#mobileNavContainer #searchContainer,
input#searchIconMain {
    width: 81%!important;
    height: 40px!important;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 8%;
}

div#mobileNavContainer input#searchIconMain {
    transform: none;
    visibility: visible;
}

div#mobileNavContainer input#searchIconMain {
    transition: .4s;
    top: -60px;
    border: none;
    font-family: bebas;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-right: -25px;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: An id (identifier) needs to be unique

Comment: Try adding type="text" to the input.

Comment: Do you mean when you click on `<input>` it doesn't fire the function `search()`? If so, try to change the event `click` to `input`.

Comment: @Max Loyd, i dont get your idea, why should "click" event on searchIconMain (which is input box) trigger "search" function

Comment: @bambam thank you that fixed it.